# Openshift/Jenkins I want to change the version of the Jenkins which is in the persistent template in the browse catalog

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-3

Actually the version which is settled in the Openshift browse catalog (openshift/jenkins-2-centos7) is the Jenkins LTS version 2.138.2 I need to change it to 2.147 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build new `jenkins` image using [jenkins-2-centos7 - Dockerfile](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins/blob/master/2/Dockerfile) after changing the version to `2.147` on your `OpenShift` cluster node.

And then import the new `jenkins` docker image into your `OpenShift` cluster.

Refer [Creating an Image Stream by Manually Pushing an Image](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/managing_images.html#creating-an-image-stream-by-manually-pushing-an-image)
 for more details about pushing `docker` image to `OCP`.

I hope it help you. :^)

Comment: I will try and then give you my feedback

Comment: Thanks Perfect Idea